# Adding ion-item to previous ion-item instead of replacing it

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am getting list of questions from api with pagination ,
I have a button which runs a function and gets next page questions .
I need to add this too previous ion-item instead of replacing it
here is my code:

```
home.html:

<div *ngFor="let question of this.questions?.data">
<ion-item class="questions_div" (click)="goToConsult(question.id);">
<p text-wrap>{{question.title}}</p> 
<span>{{question.created_at | jalali}}</span>
</ion-item>
</div>
```

What happend now is it gets second page and replaces it with first page , I need to add it bellow first ion-item

home.ts=>

```
loadMore(currentPage){
this.nextPage = ++this.currentPage;
this.showLatestQuestions(this.nextPage);}

showLatestQuestions(currentPage){
this.questionsProvider.getLatestQuestions(currentPage)
.then(data => {
  this.questions = data;
  this.currentPage = this.questions.current_page;
  return this.currentPage;
})
.catch(error => alert(error)); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just push your new question into existing array instead of assigning with new data like this -

```
 showLatestQuestions(currentPage){
this.questionsProvider.getLatestQuestions(currentPage)
.then(data => {
  for(let i=0; i< data.data.length;i++){
     this.questions.push(data.data[i]);
  }
  this.currentPage = this.questions.current_page;
  return this.currentPage;
})
.catch(error => alert(error)); 
}
```

Comment: it says property length does not exist on type {}

Comment: Now it says property data does not exist on type {}

Comment: Just try to debug it using console, it's very simple problem now